# x-axis, y-axis lines does not appear, when I include 3D chart library of HighChart in my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, 3d

I'm facing this problem in HighCharts that when I include 3D HighCharts library(exactly: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js"></script>`) in my code and want to create a 2D chart the x-axis and y-axis line disappears, when I removed  3D HighCharts library it shows me ok.
Here is a fiddle of my problem:
 [Fiddle for my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/1gaypvwh/1/)
try to remove 3D chart library from the HTML and see output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug is fixed in the newest master branch. Use version from `http://github.highcharts.com/highcharts-3d.js`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/1gaypvwh/2/

Comment: Thank you sir @Sebastian Bochan for your help I was stuck for too long in this problem, you stack overflow guys are best!